# useSubscription does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, apollo-client, subscription

When i was using `subscribeToMore` and `updateQuery` it was working, but when i use `useSubscription` and `onSubscriptionData` it doesn't. What it would be?

**it works: **

```
subscribeToMore({
        document: gqlSubscription,
        variables: {
          input: executeParams(props),
        },
        updateQuery: (prev, results) => (
           // do something with data
);
```

**it's not: **

```
useSubscription(gqlSubscription, {
    variables: {
      input: executeParams(props),
    },
    shouldResubscribe: true,
    onSubscriptionData: ({ subscriptionData }) => (
    // do something with data
);
```

Comment: What version of apollo-client are you using?

According to [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/#options), the "onSubscriptionData" is deprecated in favor of the "onData". 
Can you try using onData instead of onSubscriptionData, and see if that works?

Comment: 3.6.9.  I'm surprised, cause in other places it works. I was trying to trigger re-render with useState, but then i noticed that component was re-rendered without useState. It looks like it doesn't work at specific place.